# THREE.WebGLShader "Error: To many uniforms" when creating a lot of Point Lights

Tags: javascript, three.js, replit

## Background

I'm trying to make a ring of lights as you can see in the function below

```
function createLightRing(radius, options) {

  let nopIsDefault = false;
  
  ...
```

but when I run it a get this error

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders  THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment
ERROR: too many uniforms
1: #version 300 es
2: #define varying in
3: out highp vec4 pc_fragColor;
4: #define gl_FragColor pc_fragColor
5: #define gl_FragDepthEXT gl_FragDepth
6: #define texture2D texture
7: #define textureCube texture
...
```

I just wanted to make a ring **:(**

### What I have tried

- Lowering the radius
- Lowering the quality

### Some CODE!!!

My code is live on [repl.it](https://replit.com/), so check it out [here](https://replit.com/@ErrorbotTHE2nd/Multiverse-Front-End#javascripts/home.js)

#### My function:

```js
function createLightRing(radius, options) {

  let nopIsDefault = false;

  let lights = [];

  const defaultOptions = {
    start: 0,
    end: 360,
    copyLights: [],
    color: 0xffffff, // White
    lightType: "PointLight",
    intensity: 1,
    copyLightMap: "loop", // loops the arrays from colors and other values like it
    rotation: new p5.Vector(0, 0, 0),
    target: null,
    quality: 6,
    numberOfPoints: null,
    override: false
  }

  // applys the default to options
  options = {...defaultOptions, ...options}

  const copyLightMap = options.copyLightMap.toString().toLowerCase();
  
  // runs only if "numberOfPoints" exists
  if (!options.numberOfPoints) {
    options.numberOfPoints = (options.end - options.start) * options.quality

    nopIsDefault = true;
  }


  // Mode 1 (soft / soft-(force / end) / 1, forces the loop to end when it finishes lopping thought "copyLights", but makes sure to finnish the loop. TL;DR: Sets "numberOfPoints" to "copyLights"'s length)
  if (copyLightMap == '1' || copyLightMap == 'soft' || copyLightMap == 'soft-end' || copyLightMap == 'soft-force') {  
    options.numberOfPoints = options.copyLights.length

    nopIsDefault = true;
  }

  // updates "quality" to the right value
  options.quality = nopIsDefault ? options.quality : options.numberOfPoints / (options.end - options.start)

  for (let i = options.start; i <= options.end; i += 1 / options.quality) {
        
    let light;
    let dontCheck = false;
    let realI = (1 / options.quality) * i;


    const x = radius * cos(i);
    const y = radius * sin(i);


    // try to create a light with the spesified type
    try {
      light = new THREE[options.lightType]();
    }
    // if it fails, just use the defult
    catch(err) {
      light = new THREE[defaultOptions.lightType]();
    }

    light = setLightProprties(light, options);     // inits the light proprties

    // only runs the switch if both "copyLights" has at lest one element and it can run in the first place
    if (options.copyLights[0] && dontCheck) {

      const copyLightMap = options.copyLightMap.toString().toLowerCase();

      switch (copyLightMap) {
        
        // Mode 0 (force / end / 0, forces the loop to end when done)
        case 'force':
        case 'end':
        case '0':
          if (realI < circleLoop) {
            dontCheck = true;
            break;
          }

          light = options.copyLights[realI];
          break;
        
        // Mode 2 (loop / 2, go back to beggining copyLights when there are no more values left in it)
        case 'loop':
        case '2':
          light = options.copyLights[realI % options.copyLights.lenght];
          break;
      }
    
    }

    if (options.override) {

      light = setLightProprties(light, options);   // updates light's proprties

    }

    light.position.set(x, y, 0);   // sets the light's position

    lights.push(light);   // adds the new light to the array
  }

  return lights;
}
```

Everything else is in my [repl.it](https://replit.com/@ErrorbotTHE2nd/Multiverse-Front-End#javascripts/home.js) so go check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in your error. There are too many uniforms in your shader for the browser/platform you are using.

Open your browser to: https://webglreport.com/

Under `Vertex Shader` and `Fragment Shader` you will see a "`Max _____ Uniform Vectors:`". This is a hard limit to the size of your uniforms, and you will see different values here depending on your browser/GPU. These values are controlled by the GL implementation, and can be accessed through GL constants. Here is a run-able snippet showing how you can get to these values.

```js
const canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas')
const gl1 = canvas1.getContext('webgl')
if (gl1) {
  document.getElementById('wg1-mvuv').innerText = gl1.getParameter(gl1.MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS)
  document.getElementById('wg1-mfuv').innerText = gl1.getParameter(gl1.MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS)
}

const canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas')
const gl2 = canvas2.getContext('webgl2')
if (gl2) {
  document.getElementById('wg2-mvuv').innerText = gl2.getParameter(gl2.MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS)
  document.getElementById('wg2-mfuv').innerText = gl2.getParameter(gl2.MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS)
}
```

```css
html * {
  font-family: monospace;
}

td {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>WebGL</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS</td>
    <td id="wg1-mvuv">UNSUPPORTED</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS</td>
    <td id="wg1-mfuv">UNSUPPORTED</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <caption>WebGL 2</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS</td>
    <td id="wg2-mvuv">UNSUPPORTED</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS</td>
    <td id="wg2-mfuv">UNSUPPORTED</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Are you passing in any large arrays to a uniform, or does your (final) shader code have hundreds of uniforms? (There are WebGL inspector browser plugins to help you see the final shader code.) It is a good rule of thumb to create your shader to be as minimally-functional as possible, and then add on as memory allows.

Personally, I see this most on mobile platforms where memory is more scarce.

Comment: i see this: 
Max Vertex Uniform Vectors: 4096

Comment: anyways what is a uniform, all I did is create 360 lights

Comment: @Errorbot1122THESECOND If all you did was create lights, then please share the code you used to do that in your question. If the external resource you used the share your code ever changes or goes away, your question will lose its context.

Comment: I did @theJim01 https://replit.com/@ErrorbotTHE2nd/Multiverse-Front-End#javascripts/home.js